# Axway Titanium - Erro ao compilar quando adiciono uma biblioteca para ser usada com o Hyperloop

Tags: javascript, android, cross-compiler

Estou tentando integrar uma biblioteca do Android ao Hyperloop para usar na minha aplicação de rádio desenvolvida em Titanium, porém quando a mesma é adicionada ao projeto ocorre erro no final da compilação.

```
[INFO] :   Creating unsigned apk
[INFO] :   Processing /.../build/android/bin/dexfiles
[INFO] :   Processing /.../build/android/src
2018-01-31T16:02:49.102Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
this.abis is not a function
2018-01-31T16:02:49.102Z | ERROR  | this.abis is not a function
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Tentei recompilar a biblioteca, mudando as versões do SDK e mudando as opções do abifilter nas configurações do projeto, porém não obtive sucesso.

A biblioteca que estou tentando importar é a compilada a partir do repositório https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService.

O arquivo aar gerado pode ser baixado em: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gMywtPdRkLNIYZIBfYGu4KxIAoifpjX9/view

Tentei atualizar o hyperloop para a versão 3.0.2 beta, porém também não funcionou.

Obrigado pela ajuda.